# Cannot "slide to unlock" when iPhone is in dock. Any idea why?

Tags: iphone

I have a third-party iPhone dock connected directly to the mains. I found that I cannot unlock my iPhone 3GS when it is in the dock. The slider just slides back and doesn't follow the finger's movement completely.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Strange issue...

I would guess that the dock is somehow interfering with the capacitive 'field' of the screen. You could confirm this by unlocking the device before connecting it to the dock and see if the rest of the interface is affected in the same way.

Though I guess the only way to proceed would be to get the dock replaced (if it's under warranty) and see if that fixes the problem or buy a different one.

Comment: It's not important enough an issue to do much about it, I guess. The screen works when it is unlocked. It's just that the phone refuses to unlock when in that dock. Maybe it's supposed to do this?